# Concurrent request in rails thin server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I have deployed my application in thin server.I am facing issue with multi thread instances.For instance,I am executing some Bulk Operation localhost:3000/bulk which is currently running.If I am opening same page in another browser.It is not loading until that bulk execution completed.How to solve this issue?

Comment: I've never used thin, but you can play with the config https://github.com/macournoyer/thin#configuration-files specially the `threaded` and `servers` options.

Comment: Ok Thanks.Do you have idea about Puma server?